# Problems in looping an AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I need to loop through an AdvancedDataGrid's tree. Can anyone explain me some things?

This is my code:

```
var adg : AdvancedDataGrid;

var dp : GroupingCollection2 = adg.dataProvider;
var cursor:IViewCursor=dp.createCursor();
```

Now my issue is that I don't know how to access my objects from here. My AdvancedDataGrid has as dataprovider an GroupingCollection2 that has an XML as source, and also is grouped by "Project_Name" field from XML.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
var dp:Object=MyDG.dataProvider;
var cursor:IViewCursor=dp.createCursor();

while( !cursor.afterLast )
{
// Access each column field like: cursor.current.MyFieldName
trace(cursor.current.MyFieldName);
// Obviously don't forget to move to next row:
cursor.moveNext();
}
```

[source](http://blog.crankybit.com/looping-through-datagrid-rows-in-flex/)

This might also be useful: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IViewCursor.html

This example could also be useful: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/04/15/creating-a-view-cursor-on-an-arraycollection-in-flex/